# Salesforce Android SDK - SyncDown creates two records of custom object

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android, sdk

Below is the scenario which we are facing now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Step 1: Create account rest request

Step 2: Request sent out and received by salesforce and record is created

Step 3: Internet goes down, so mobile app do not get SalesForce ID

```
RestRequest req = null;
Map<String, Object> orderMap = Order.getOrderToSubmit(mNewItem);

if(mOrder.getId() != null && !mOrder.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("null") && !mOrder.getId().isEmpty()) {
    req = RestRequest.getRequestForUpdate(syncManager.apiVersion, Order.OBJECT_TYPE,
    mOrder.getId(), orderMap);
} else {
    req = RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(syncManager.apiVersion, Order.OBJECT_TYPE, orderMap);
}
RestResponse res = syncManager.sendSyncWithSmartSyncUserAgent(req);
```

## Internet goes down after "res" call, so the record is created in SF but local order soup does not have SF ID

When internet/mobile data is available, the app does sync down and it creates one additional record which has SFID

The sync down option are as follows:

```
ParentInfo parentInfo = new ParentInfo(
        Order.OBJECT_TYPE,
        Order.SOUP_NAME,
        Constants.ID,
        Constants.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
);
ChildrenInfo childrenInfo = new ChildrenInfo(
        OrderItem.OBJECT_TYPE,
        OrderItem.PARENT_REL_NAME,
        OrderItem.SOUP_NAME,
        OrderItem.PARENT_ID_NAME,
        Constants.ID,
        Constants.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
);
```

Ideally, the app should merge records based on a account and purchase order number. if it matches, assign the SFID to local soup.
How can we handle this scenario?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/entity_framework_sync_related.htm?search_text=ParentChildrenSyncDownTarget

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?